# compile Qt with qmake and make

Tags: qt, cmd, makefile, qmake

I need help about Qt files compiling with cmd. I chose the directory but I still have error about    "qmake" and "make" commands.

I cant qmake or make . I am showing the cmd directories. but I cant compile it. which directory I need to use???

---

```
C:\Users\foo>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F224-008C

 Directory of C:\Users\foo

18.07.2013  09:42    <DIR>          .
18.07.2013  09:42    <DIR>          ..
17.07.2013  12:27    <DIR>          ipch
17.07.2013  16:41    <DIR>          QtTab
18.07.2013  09:42        21.450.752 QtTab.sdf
11.07.2013  11:17               882 QtTab.sln
11.07.2013  11:22    <DIR>          Win32
               2 File(s)     21.451.634 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  103.678.271.488 bytes free

C:\Users\foo>qmake
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


C:\Users\foo>make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\foo>cd qttab

C:\Users\foo>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F224-008C

 Directory of C:\Users\foo

17.07.2013  16:41    <DIR>          .
17.07.2013  16:41    <DIR>          ..
17.07.2013  16:42    <DIR>          Debug
17.07.2013  16:41    <DIR>          GeneratedFiles
17.07.2013  16:41               308 main.cpp
11.07.2013  11:17               130 qttab.cpp
11.07.2013  11:17               254 qttab.h
11.07.2013  11:17                65 qttab.qrc
17.07.2013  16:41             1.353 qttab.ui
11.07.2013  11:17            10.830 QtTab.vcxproj
11.07.2013  11:17             2.659 QtTab.vcxproj.filters
11.07.2013  11:22               609 QtTab.vcxproj.user
11.07.2013  11:17    <DIR>          Resources
17.07.2013  12:28             1.994 foo.ui
               9 File(s)         18.202 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  103.678.271.488 bytes free

C:\Users\foo>qmake
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using windows it seems you should use nmake, not make - see

[qt documentation on compilation under windows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-win.html)

Comment: You need to open a VS console (in the start menu)/source vcallvars.bat (or similar, don't remember the exact name) and add Qt's bin/ dir (the one qmake.exe resides in) to the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Expand your `PATH` System variable to include the QT-InstallationDir/bin (this is where qmake is) and run the `vcvars.bat` file from your MSVC2010 Installation Directory in your cmd prior to starting compiling (alternate use the cmd shortcut provided in your startmenu in the folder of MSVC)